# How to use a python context manager inside a generator

Tags: python, generator, with-statement

In python, should with-statements be used inside a generator? To be clear, I am not asking about using a decorator to create a context manager from a generator function. I am asking whether there is an inherent issue using a with-statement as a context manager inside a generator as it will catch `StopIteration` and `GeneratorExit` exceptions in at least some cases. Two examples follow.

A good example of the issue is raised by Beazley's example (page 106). I have modified it to use a with statement so that the files are explicitly closed after the yield in the opener method. I have also added two ways that an exception can be thrown while iterating the results.

```
import os
import fnmatch

def find_files(topdir, pattern):
    for path, dirname, filelist in os.walk(topdir):
        for name in filelist:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                yield os.path.join(path,name)
def opener(filenames):
    f = None
    for name in filenames:
        print "F before open: '%s'" % f
        #f = open(name,'r')
        with open(name,'r') as f:
            print "Fname: %s, F#: %d" % (name, f.fileno())
            yield f
            print "F after yield: '%s'" % f
def cat(filelist):
    for i,f in enumerate(filelist):
        if i ==20:
            # Cause and exception
            f.write('foobar')
        for line in f:
            yield line
def grep(pattern,lines):
    for line in lines:
        if pattern in line:
            yield line

pylogs = find_files("/var/log","*.log*")
files = opener(pylogs)
lines = cat(files)
pylines = grep("python", lines)
i = 0
for line in pylines:
    i +=1
    if i == 10:
        raise RuntimeError("You're hosed!")

print 'Counted %d lines\n' % i
```

In this example, the context manager successfully closes the files in the opener function. When an exception is raised, I see the trace back from the exception, but the generator stops silently. If the with-statement catches the exception why doesn't the generator continue?

When I define my own context managers for use inside a generator. I get runtime errors saying that I have ignored a `GeneratorExit`. For example:

```
class CManager(object):  
    def __enter__(self):
          print "  __enter__"
          return self
    def __exit__(self, exctype, value, tb):
        print "  __exit__; excptype: '%s'; value: '%s'" % (exctype, value)
        return True

def foo(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        with CManager() as cman:
            cman.val = i
            yield cman
# Case1 
for item in foo(10):
    print 'Pass - val: %d' % item.val
# Case2
for item in foo(10):
    print 'Fail - val: %d' % item.val
    item.not_an_attribute
```

This little demo works fine in case1 with no exceptions raised, but fails in case2 where an attribute error is raised. Here I see a `RuntimeException` raised because the with statement has caught and ignored a `GeneratorExit` exception.

Can someone help clarify the rules for this tricky use case? I suspect it is something I am doing, or not doing in my `__exit__` method. I tried adding code to re-raise `GeneratorExit`, but that did not help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from the [Data model entry for `object.__exit__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__)

> If an exception is supplied, and the method wishes to suppress the exception (i.e., prevent it from being propagated), it should return a true value. Otherwise, the exception will be processed normally upon exit from this method.

In your `__exit__` function, you're returning `True` which will suppress *all* exceptions.  If you change it to return `False`, the exceptions will continue to be raised as normal (with the only difference being that you guarantee that your `__exit__` function gets called and you can make sure to clean up after yourself)

For example, changing the code to:

```
def __exit__(self, exctype, value, tb):
    print "  __exit__; excptype: '%s'; value: '%s'" % (exctype, value)
    if exctype is GeneratorExit:
        return False
    return True
```

allows you to do the right thing and not suppress the `GeneratorExit`.  Now you *only* see the attribute error.  Maybe the rule of thumb should be the same as with any Exception handling -- **only intercept Exceptions if you know how to handle them**.  Having an `__exit__` return `True` is on par (maybe slightly worse!) than having a bare except:

```
try:
   something()
except: #Uh-Oh
   pass
```

---

Note that when the `AttributeError` is raised (and not caught), I believe that causes the reference count on your generator object to drop to 0 which then triggers a `GeneratorExit` exception within the generator so that it can clean itself up.  Using my `__exit__`, play around with the following two cases and hopefully you'll see what I mean:

```
try:
    for item in foo(10):
        print 'Fail - val: %d' % item.val
        item.not_an_attribute
except AttributeError:
    pass

print "Here"  #No reference to the generator left.  
              #Should see __exit__ before "Here"
```

and

```
g = foo(10)
try:
    for item in g:
        print 'Fail - val: %d' % item.val
        item.not_an_attribute
except AttributeError:
    pass

print "Here"
b = g  #keep a reference to prevent the reference counter from cleaning this up.
       #Now we see __exit__ *after* "Here"
```

Comment: @mgilson Thanks for your great answer.
It seems that the generator function is not what catches the attribute error. That is the behavior that I wanted, but it seems it is not possible. I want to use one with-statement to centralize the exception handling in a sequence of generators.

Comment: @David -- context managers are something that I've been working with a decent amount as of late, so they're fresh on my mind :).  It was a good question.  I wish all new users asked such nice first questions :).

Comment: @lukecampbell -- I'm glad you liked it :).  It was an interesting question for sure.

Comment: @mgilson Between Beazley and and stackoverflow I have spent three years finding existing answers without ever having to ask a question.

Comment: With-statements are really great - even if they can't fit this use case. I did some work with @lukecampbell last summer using with-statements and redis to coordinate distributed processes: [gist](https://gist.github.com/dstuebe/5143032)

Comment: @David -- That's neat:).  I've asked a few.  Occassionally I'll have a question, and a google search doesn't show anything.  Even if I have an idea how to go about solving the problem I sometimes ask in hopes that it will be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

```
class CManager(object):
    def __enter__(self):
          print "  __enter__"
          return self
    def __exit__(self, exctype, value, tb):
        print "  __exit__; excptype: '%s'; value: '%s'" % (exctype, value)
        if exctype is None:
            return

        # only re-raise if it's *not* the exception that was
        # passed to throw(), because __exit__() must not raise
        # an exception unless __exit__() itself failed.  But throw()
        # has to raise the exception to signal propagation, so this
        # fixes the impedance mismatch between the throw() protocol
        # and the __exit__() protocol.
        #
        if sys.exc_info()[1] is not (value or exctype()):
            raise
```

Comment: The docs state that `__exit__` isn't supposed to re-raise the exception passed in ...

Comment: @mgilson, Odd...I pinched the idea from contextlib.py

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know why you *shouldn't* ... Although I don't know why you would want to either.  If you return a `False-y` value, the exception continues to propagate anyway.

Comment: @mgilson, I added the relevant explanation