# Does using a context manager in a generator may lead to resources leak?

Tags: python-3.x, generator, contextmanager

I have a function that *yields* from a context manager:

```
def producer(pathname):
    with open(pathname) as f:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(4)
            if not chunk:
               break
            yield chunk
```

It is not a problem when the generator is entirely consumed since, during the last iteration, the generator resumes execution after the yield statement, and the loop breaks and we nicely exit the context manager.

However, if the generator is only *partially consumed*, and there are *no more consumers* to consume it entirely, will the generator remain suspended *forever*? In that case, we will never exit from the context manager. Would that mean the file will remain open for the rest of the program execution? Or at least until the generator is garbage collected? Is this a corner case I should take care of by myself, or can I rely on the Python runtime to *close* dangling context manager in time?

---

FWIW, I've seen [Generator and context manager at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355310/generator-and-context-manager-at-the-same-time) and [How to use a python context manager inside a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353220/how-to-use-a-python-context-manager-inside-a-generator) but I don't think they really answer the same question. Unless I missed something?

Comment: *Is this an issue?* - it's "for granted": in that case a context manager comes under generator control, thus obeying the generator's "suspend" nature.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Roman. _Is this an issue?_ I think I was not as clear as I would have hoped it.  I was not questioning the fact the context manager is suspended. But the fact it may be suspended _forever_ if there are no more consumers using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you fail to consume the whole generator, the context manager won't be cleaned until the generator is garbage collected, which may take quite a while if reference cycles are involved, or you're running on a non-CPython interpreter.

You can work around this by `close`-ing the generator-iterator; all generator functions provide [a `close` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.close) on the resulting generator-iterator that raises `GeneratorExit` inside it; the exception bubbles out of `with` statements and the like to make sure they're properly cleaned deterministically.

To make it occur at a guaranteed point in time, you can [use `contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) to get guaranteed closing of the generator itself:

```
 from contextlib import closing

 with closing(producer(mypath)) as produced_items:
     for item in produced_items:
         # Do stuff, maybe break loop early
```

Even if you `break`, `return`, or raise an exception, the `with` controlling `produced_items` will `close` it, which will in turn invoke cleanup for the `with` statements within it.